# sprintf_s caused for crash

Tags: c++, error-handling, printf

I meet problem.
Example:

```
try
{
    char strMes[6];
    sprintf_s(strMes, sizeof(strMes), "%s", "012345678");
    printf(strMes);
}
catch(...)
{
    printf("Wrong\n");
}
```

In debug environment it caused for debugger "buffer too small" message.

In release environment it caused for crash.

I tried to replace  try-catch block to __try-__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) block, but I get the same behavior.

I have about 1K callings for sprintf_s function, so replace sprintf_s to _snprintf_s is not option for me. (see [sprintf_s with a buffer too small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505986/sprintf-s-with-a-buffer-too-small))

Please help!

Comment: What were you expecting? you are trying to write past the end of a buffer, either limit your write to the size of the buffer (which in your case you can do in a decent editor with a simple search/replace) or enlarge the buffer.

Comment: Make the buffer(s) bigger / Replace `sprintf_s` with `_snprintf` which takes the same parameters.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I believe you should **use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf_s`**.

Second, there is an [invalid paramater handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9yf33zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for CRT that gets called. Try setting that.

Answer (score 1):

You *must* check the return value of `sprintf_s` before using `strMes` any further. Otherwise how do you know whether the buffer was big enough?
`sprinft_s` may have nothing written to `strMes` and so it is still uninitialized. That's what's causing the crash (try removing the `sprintf_s`, it likely crashes as well.)

From the `sprintf_s` docs:

> The number of characters written, or –1 if an error occurred. If
>   buffer or format is a null pointer, sprintf_s and swprintf_s return -1
>   and set errno to EINVAL.

PS: You should tag this question C++ not C due to try/catch.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> .... If either check fails, the invalid parameter handler is invoked, as
>   described in Parameter Validation ...

The default behaviour is throwing. You can [override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9yf33zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) it.

Answer (score 0):

If your VS version supports, you should run Code Analysis on it.

Read about [About Code Analysis](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/codeanalysis.aspx)